# How to implement Azure Cloud Service's RoleEntryPoint.OnStop method in Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-cloud-services

When Azure shuts down a Cloud Service instance (e.g. when the host OS reboots, or when autoscaling down), it triggers a Stop method, so applications have a chance to gracefully shutdown.

I can find documentation how to do this in .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.roleentrypoint.onstop.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1 but I cannot find any documentation on how to do this from Java.

How can I do this in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [com.microsoft.windowsazure.serviceruntime.RoleEnvironmentStoppingListener](http://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/windowsazure/serviceruntime/RoleEnvironmentStoppingListener.html)

This is available from Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.microsoft.azure|azure-serviceruntime|0.6.0|jar

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to access Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll via the JNI, but I don't know of any existing implementations.